# Returning a single key value from an array with multiple identical values?

Tags: ios, arrays, object

I have an array of objects(images) with key values of @"titleLabel" stored on a backend server(parse). What I am trying to do is display the list of titles in a pickerView but I only want to display ONE title for every group of @"titleLabels" whose keys match. For example: if I have five objects(images) with titleLabel key: 'Spring Break' I only want to display one instance of the title 'Spring Break' and not all five. The code I have written is my best amateur shot at solving it but my NSLog for 'titles array count' is returning a value of 1 and  when I log the value I get all of the titles again.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Images"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
           NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for(id obj in self.objectsArray){
            PFObject *key = [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];
            if(![dict objectForKey:key]){
                [dict setValue:obj forKey:key];
            }
        }
        for (id key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
        NSLog(@"Objects array is %d", [self.objectsArray count]);
        NSLog(@"Titles array is %d", [self.titlesArray count]);
        }
        [self.pickerView reloadComponent:0];
        }
    }];
```

And here is where I define my keys in a separate controller:

```
 PFObject *image = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Images"];
        [image setObject:self.releaseDate forKey:@"releaseDate"];
        [image setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
        [image setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
        [image setObject:title forKey:@"titleLabel"];
        [image setObject:deadline forKey:@"deadline"];
        [image setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
        [image setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
        [image setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
        [image saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PFObject *object = [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];

if(object != [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"]){
      self.titlesArray = [self.titlesArray arrayByAddingObject:object];

}
```

you are checking if the object is equal to what you just assigned. Also, you should be using a NSMutableArray but if you dont care, i dont care too. :) Saying that, i guess your else loop should look like this

```
    self.objectsArray = objects;

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for(id obj in self.objectsArray){
        PFObject *key = [self.objectsArray valueForKey:@"titleLabel"];
        if(![dict objectForKey:key]){
            [dict setValue:obj forKey:key];
        }
    }
    for (id key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }
```

Comment: I tried to convert it over to NSMutableArray before but it throws an error of 'incompatible block pointer'... which because of my limited knowledge, I don't fully understand. I do understand why it needs to be mutable though, just not how to update the already written code. Also, I found a `addUniqueObjectsFromArray:forKey:` operation on parse and tried to implement it instead, however even that is not working correctly. any advice?

Comment: A couple of questions here. Did you try my code? Also, you cannot assign (NSArray *) returned from arrayByAddingObject to NSMutableArray. That is why I suggested you to use a dictionary object, the best part about using dictionary is you can add an array object to the corresponding key "springBreak". So that all your images corresponding to springbreak are in one place.

Comment: I gotcha. Yeah i did but it throws up an error `Incompatible pointer types sending 'PFObject *' to parameter of type 'NSString` on the key string of this line `[dict setValue:obj forKey:key];` and i haven't been able to work around it. I kinda get what your saying about using dictionary, that's exactly what I want...just can't get it to work. (only about a month and a half into self taught iOS with no prior programming experience, still learning to say the least)

Comment: I looked into it and from as far as I can tell, the key SHOULD be a string. When the picker loads the titleLabel's as the components, the key "titleLabel" is loaded as a string, so I don't get why it's not letting me assign it in the dictionary. I've been fiddling around with different values and logs but haven't been able to come up with anything that works. (I've updated my code to include your code as well as my declaration of PFObject keys)

Comment: Jared, if you find my answer helpful to find single KV from identical values, close it. you need to open under parse a different question how to find the value. thanks